# NetStream: dual threshold buffering, and seeking beyond buffer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, buffering, netstream

[This](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/fms_dual_buffering.html) was a helpful article about dual threshold buffering. It explains that you can listen for the `NetStream.Buffer.Full` and `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` events on a `NetStream` and adjust the `NetStream`'s buffer time accordingly to make the best use of available bandwidth and also get fast video start times. I've encountered a problem though. When I seek past the buffered section of video in my NetStream, the buffer is once again empty, but I don't get a `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` event. The `NetStream`'s buffer time is still set to my expanded buffer time so I lose the advantage of a fast start time. How do you implement this strategy so that it works properly in this case? How do you tell that the buffer is empty again or that you have seeked past the available buffer?

Edit: I should probably mention I am using in-buffer seeking (Smart Seeking). I think this wouldn't be a problem if I wasn't, because flash flushes the buffer on every seek without this feature enabled.

Comment: That article is very helpful for buffering long streams yes but I think you can use some of the logic there. A low buffer threshold  at the buffer empty when seek should aid in continued playback. Seek does change things quite a bit though. I have to ask though, is seek really what the client needs? If it is a user initiated action to seek then its not asking too much of them to buffer playback. That should be an acceptable user experience. If they want to seek, they should be willing to wait until their content is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to just reset the buffer time on every seek. You'll still get the `NetStream.Buffer.Full` event, and it'll fire immediately if you happen to seek to a location where the buffer is already larger your minimum buffer, so your handler for `NetStream.Buffer.Full` will just immediately set the buffer time back to your expanded buffer time. Here's an example:

```
var videoStream:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

videoStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function (event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch(event.info.code) {
        case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":
            // this will keep the buffer filling continuously while there is bandwidth
            videoStream.bufferTime = Settings.maxBuffer;
            State.buffering = false;
            break;
        case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
            // if we run out of buffer we'll reset the buffer time to the min
            videoStream.bufferTime = Settings.minBuffer;
            State.buffering = true;
            break;
    }
}

_view.addEventListener(SeekEvent.SEEK, function (event:SeekEvent):void {
    State.buffering = true;
    videoStream.bufferTime = Settings.minBuffer;
    videoStream.seek(event.seek * (_duration || 0));
});
```